# Restricting the constructor-access to certain classes

Tags: php, oop, access-modifiers

Let's say I want to restrict the access to the constructor of a public class, so that only certain classes may create an instance of it, but all classes are able to use the instance.

In Java, I know two ways to archive this:

1. Make a `public static` inner class with a `private` constructor and instantiate it in the outer class.
2. Make the classes constructor package-private (restricts access to all classes in the same package).

In PHP however, there are no inner classes and the namespaces (which are close to packages) have no own access-modifier (ergo no package-private).

So, how can I protect the access to the classes constructor?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to get namespace of caller class and if it's not in the same namespace as you class with protected constructor throw runtime exception.

Comment: A class should not know anything about who uses it to keep the system extensible. Some piece of code may depend on an instance of another class, but why does that instance have to depend on/know about its user?

Comment: @deceze I guess OP has Java/.Net background where package private/internal classes are very useful. Actually, there would not be big benefit from them if they were available.